# UINotificationFeedbackGenerator with type error [ObjC]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I searched the web for UIFeedbackGenerators only finds things about UIImpactFeedbackGenerators. But in my case I want an APP to perform specific Haptic Feedbacks when for example the login failed. So I am trying to create a UINotificationFeedbackTypeError. I don't know how to set my generator to the Type Error

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImpactFeedbackGenerator *impactFeedbackGenerator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINotificationFeedbackGenerator *generator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.button addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Choose between heavy, medium, and light for style
    self.impactFeedbackGenerator = [[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator alloc] initWithStyle:UIImpactFeedbackStyleMedium];

    // Primes feedback generator for upcoming events and reduces latency
    [self.impactFeedbackGenerator prepare];




    [self.button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(didPressButton2:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.generator = [[UINotificationFeedbackGenerator alloc] init];

    [self.generator prepare];

}

- (void)didPressButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Triggers haptic
    [self.impactFeedbackGenerator impactOccurred];
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}

- (void)didPressButton2:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // Triggers haptic
    [self.generator impactOccurred];
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}


@end
```

Comment: `[self.generator notificationOccurred: UINotificationFeedbackTypeError]`?

Comment: oh well that was easy thx @lame